How many players dropping off while loading a mobile game is considered normal?
What percentage of players who do not wait for the full launch of a mobile game can I consider acceptable as a developer? Could you recommend research and/or articles on this topic?
I am interested in specific numbers and their justification.

that would be entirely your decision, or your employer's decision

"Acceptable" is 100% subjective. Maybe you should instead look at how long your game takes to load and what you can do to reduce this.

If I take a look at some steam games and see how big in % the achievement for Finished the tutorial is, I wonder why they installed it in the first place

@Zibelas During Steam sales, it's common for players to make impulse purchases. They may not be planning to play the game right away, but still download and start it because that's the closest you get to unboxing with a digital purchase. Then they go back to playing whatever they've been recently, then play some other game they're excited about, and eventually forget about the impulse purchase.
